# If condition doesn't work

Tags: c, if-statement

I have this part of code:

```
void query(hash_t* params) {
record_t* rec;

// Coordinator, opgroup and  Opcode  specified by the client
uint64_t netid = 0;
uint8_t op_code_group = 0;
uint8_t op_code = 0;
char* par;
now = mdl_now();
/* set the start and end time based on query parameters */
...........
// Network id is required
par = hash_get(params, "netid");
...........
netid = strtoull(par, NULL, 10);
par = hash_get(params, "opcode_group");
...........
op_code_group = strtoul(par, NULL, 10);
par = hash_get(params, "opcode");
...........
op_code = strtoul(par, NULL, 10);
/* seek in the bytestream */
mdl_seek(start);
while((rec = (record_t* ) mdl_next(&ts)) != NULL) {
    ...............
    // Only print records with the wanted net and opcodes
    if((netid != 0) && (netid != NTOHLL(rec->net_id))) 
        continue;
    if((opcode_group != 0) && (op_code_group != ntohl(rec->opcode_group))) 
        continue;
    if((opcode != 0) && (op_code != ntohl(rec->opcode)))
        continue;
    ..............
    mdl_print("%u %llu %u %u %u %d\n", 
        sec, 
        NTOHLL(rec->net_id), 
        rec->op_code_group, 
        rec->op_code, 
        rec->payloadlength, 
        val);
     }
 }
```

opcode_group, opcode and the other parameters are passed to the query class via http request.

This is the question:
if I specify a opcode_group for example = 160, the result don't show me anything. If, instead, I specify opcode_group = 0 (all the records) the result show me all the records, included records with opcode_group = 160.

Where is the error? Thank you very much.

Comment: Now would be a good time to start to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: A debugger is very good at helping you find bugs. Use it!

Comment: Can you say me a debugger for CentOS? I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Yes - gdb is the obvious choice - there are lots of gdb tutorials out there. Or you can just add some printfs in your code to help you work out what's going on.

Comment: Try gdb ... probably already installed, if not there's definitely a centos package for it

Comment: Ok but I call this class via http , not via command line... How can I do the debug? Please help me, where is the error in this if statement?

Comment: I call the class with a http request like this:
(http://localhost:44444/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s)

Comment: If learning gdb is to much work for you, why don't you do some `printf` debugging? Print the values for all parameters in the `if` statements.

Comment: I would do! but I can't print rec->opcode_group because is a parameter that everywhen is read from the stream. I already try with the print :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see the code and find only getting the value in variable "**op_code_group**" and not "**opcode_group**"

```
op_code_group = strtoul(par, NULL, 10);
```

I believe u r messing with similar variables

_EDITED_*_*__*_*__

I believe the problem is with this part

```
if((opcode_group != 0) && (op_code_group != ntohl(rec->opcode_group))) 
    continue;"
```

This part will fail and print the record only if opcode_group == 0

Modify this to

```
if((opcode_group == 0) || (op_code_group != ntohl(rec->opcode_group))) 
    continue;"
```

Guess u r facing the same probs with netid and op_code too

Comment: In the previous version variables and parameters are both opcode_group and opcode. Next I thinked that the problem was the same name, so I changed the local variables in op_code_group and op_code. But the problem was not fixed.

Comment: @sharkbait please find the edited answer

Comment: Doesn't work. You're solution don't show nothing anymore. Also when I call the class with this http request http://131.114.52.207:44444/ztc_config?netid=0&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-20s&end=-1s that should show every record in the stream

Comment: Anyway, opcode_group isn't a local variable. I can't use. I can only use op_code_group. But it doesn't work.

Comment: u need to change the conditions in same way for netid and opcode too

Comment: Yes I have the same problem with opcode. But not with netid haha I don't know why.

Comment: The only difference I can see is u use "strtoull" for netid and for others u use "strtoul"

Comment: Because netid is uint64_t, opcode_group and opcode are uint8_t

Comment: did u tried by modifying the code same way for netid and op_code..

Comment: yes but I obtain an error because opcode_group and opcode are uint8_t and I have to use only strtoul

Comment: i dont mean it... use the same code if((opcode_group == 0) || (op_code_group != ntohl(rec->opcode_group))) 
    continue;" for netid and op_code too